# column count doesnt match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem inserting data from the list view to MySQL. This is what i've got so far. The error says column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
    Dim sql As String
    Dim con = New MySqlConnection("data source=localhost; user id=root; password=pwd;          database=db;")
    Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand
    Dim lvitem As Object
    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim iLoop As Integer

    iCount = ListPayroll.Items.Count()
    Try
        If Not ListPayroll.Items.Count = 0 Then
            Do Until iLoop = ListPayroll.Items.Count
                lvitem = ListPayroll.Items.Item(iLoop)
                With lvitem
                    con.Open()
                    sql = "INSERT INTO attendancelist (empno, line1, time1, line2, time2, line3, time3, line4, time4, line5, time5, line6, time6) values('" & .SubItems(0).text & "','" & .SubItems(1).text & "','" & .SubItems(2).Text & "','" & .SubItems(3).Text & "','" & .SubItems(4).Text & "','" & .SubItems(5).Text & "', '" & .SubItems(6).Text & "', '" & .SubItems(7).Text & "', '" & .SubItems(8).Text & "','" & .SubItems(9).Text & "', '" & .SubItems(10).Text & "', '" & .SubItems(11).Text & "', '" & .SubItems(12).Text & "', '" & .SubItems(13).Text & "')"
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.CommandText = sql
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
                iLoop = iLoop + 1
                lvitem = Nothing
                con.Close()
                MessageBox.Show("Record Saved!")
            Loop
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: Wow, you're wonderfully open to SQL Injection.  You should be using parameterized queries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to insert 14 values into 13 columns.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry Im a bit disoriented this past few days developing this payroll system. :P

Comment: It works great but now the messagebox wont stop displaying. How can i make it to one general prompt?

Comment: Ill try to move my message box out of the loop